# What to put in () of ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

I know that the () in `ArrayList<Integer> = new ArrayList<>()` can be used to describe the capacity for the `ArrayList`, but recently I've seen people put `ArrayList`s in the `()` of other `ArrayList`s.

I wasn't able to find the answer from searching on Google multiple times, any ideas?

Comment: ArrayList class has multiple constructors that take different arguments. Read the javadoc

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: javadoc is helpful for knowing the Constructor,data fields,method of a class, what is the parent of the class, etc. Whenever you don't understand a built in java class just search the javadoc for it in google.

Answer (score 1):

This is a call to the [`ArrayList(Collection<T>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-) constructor. It creates a new array list with the elements of the `Collection` (e.g., another `ArrayList`) being passed to the constructor.